# checkboxes checked outside input

Tags: html, css

I don't know why when I click on email2@mail.com for example my first checkbox is checked...
I made a fiddle to illustrate my issue ...

http://jsfiddle.net/pZ8jY/

```html
<table class="checkboxes">
   <tr>
    <td >
    <label for="CheckBoxOne"><input id="CheckBoxOne" type="checkbox"  value=" test@mail.com " />
        <span>test@mail.com </span></label></td>

          <td >
    <label for="CheckBoxOne"><input id="CheckBoxOne" type="checkbox"  value=" test2@mail.com " />
        <span>test2@mail.com </span></label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```css
.checkboxes label
{ 
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

.checkboxes input
{ 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.checkboxes label span
{
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Comment: They have the same `id`. So, only the first is affected. You should only use an `id` once.

Answer (score 1):

Ids must be unique.

```
<input id="CheckBoxTwo" type="checkbox"  value=" test2@mail.com " />
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the same `id` twice. 
You mean for those checkboxes to be different so use different Id's.
Labels work in the sense that if you click your mouse with the pointer on the `label` text, 
The clicks apply to the input field they correspond to.
Now, in your code you are pointing both the labels to the same `id`. So clicking on "test" and "test2" apply to the first visible input element that has the `id` "CheckboxOne" in the source code. This is causing it to check the first checkbox

Also, if you are looking forward to post all this data from a form, it is `"name"` you need to use, not the id.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the checkboxes outside the label and assigning different ids

```
<table class="checkboxes">
  <tr>
    <td >
      <label for="CheckBoxOne"><span>test@mail.com </span></label>
      <input id="CheckBoxOne" type="checkbox"  value=" test@mail.com " />
    </td>
    <td >
      <label for="CheckBoxOne2"><span>test2@mail.com </span></label>
      <input id="CheckBoxOne2" type="checkbox"  value=" test2@mail.com " />
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: You are still using the same ID.